# Swift: location not being updated when returned from background

Tags: swift, core-location

I have a Swift app that I am trying to update the location when the app is returned from the background, but it doesn't seem to work when returned from the background.

On launch of the app, I'll get the location just fine.  After getting the location I call stopUpdatingLocation() so I don't continue to get the location:
    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

Then, in my AppDelegate.swift I startUpdatingLocation again:

```
func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {

    ViewController().locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}
```

This is my code so far:

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

var locationManager = CLLocationManager()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didFailWithError error: NSError!) {
    println("Error while updating location " + error.localizedDescription)
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {

    var userLocation:CLLocation = locations[0] as CLLocation

    println("\(userLocation.coordinate.latitude),\(userLocation.coordinate.longitude)")

    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

}

}
```

However, whenever I background the app (click home), and then return to the app the location isn't updated.  Any idea what I might be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `applicationWillEnterForeground`, the code is creating a new, local instance of `ViewController` that is never displayed, does not yet have a `locationManager` created and so has no effect.

It is not referring to the `ViewController` instance that already exists and is displayed (and has the `locationManager` instance that was originally started).

Instead, it should get a reference to the existing instance.  Assuming `ViewController` is the root view controller, you could do:

```
func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {

    if let rvc = window?.rootViewController as? ViewController {
        rvc.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

}
```

---

However, it might be better practice to let the `ViewController` class itself manage its own behavior.  This way, the app delegate doesn't have to find a reference to the view controller's instance and it doesn't directly access the view controller's internal state and `ViewController` becomes more self-contained.

In addition to the app delegate method `applicationWillEnterForeground`, it's possible to monitor these events from anywhere using the `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification` notification.

In `ViewController`, you can register and unregister for the notification in (for example) `viewWillAppear` and `viewWillDisappear`.  When registering, you indicate which method to call for the event and everything is handled inside `ViewController` (and the code in `applicationWillEnterForeground` can be removed).

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(
        self, 
        selector: "willEnterForegound", 
        name: UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification, 
        object: nil)
}

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(
        self, 
        name: UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification, 
        object: nil)
}

func willEnterForegound() {
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}
```

Comment: Thanks Anna, makes perfect sense, not sure how I missed that it was creating a new instance of ViewController, not using the existing.